# CSS file of a component within a library does not get loaded with the component in angular app

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular-cli, angular-library

I have developed a library in an angular application (which is generated using angular cli) and the library contains a component with its own template file and stylesheet. However, when I load the module in the `app.module.ts` and run the app (using ng serve for simplicity), the styles within the stylesheet are not rendered.

- The library is generated using `ng generate library`
- The library is contained within the `projects` directory of the app
- The component is present within `<name of the component>/src/lib` directory

The `app.module.ts` file contains the following code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GuitarChordGeneratorModule } from 'projects/guitar-chord-generator/src/public-api';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        GuitarChordGeneratorModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Below is a snippet from the `guitar-chord-generator.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Chord } from './chord';
import { GCSGConfig } from './gcsgconfig';

@Component({
    selector: 'lib-guitar-chord-generator',
    templateUrl: './guitar-chord-generator.component.html',
    styles: ['./guitar-chord-generator.component.css']
})
```

The image below is the directory structure of the app.

[image]

As you can see that `guitar-chord-generator.component.css` is the CSS file for the component.

Comment: What's in your `guitar-chord-generator.component.ts` file. Do you have the styleUrl specified?

Comment: Yes. I am updating the component in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component has

```
styles: ['./guitar-chord-generator.component.css']
```

> The [styles property](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) takes an array of strings that contain CSS code.

You should be using `styleUrls`

```
styleUrls: ['./guitar-chord-generator.component.css']
```